# Yum installation not adding library files

Tags: c, centos, yum

For some reason, my yum installer does not link library files. For example, I am trying to include  in a c file, so I run sudo yum install c-ares. Everything installs, but when I run the program, I get the error:

**fatal error: ares.h: No such file or directory**

The same thing happens when I try to include other packages, such as

Any thoughts on how I can get yum to put these libraries in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are usually two packages - one containing the library so you can run existing programs and another for development that contains the headers that has the name with "-devel" appended to it.

So in this case you need to also install "c-ares-devel"

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the development packages. Like c-ares-devel